# Proving that size with filter is not equal to (size + 1)

Tags: coq, ssreflect

Having this theorem:

```
Lemma all_count T (a : pred T) s :
  all a s = (count a s == size s).
Proof.
  elim: s=> [| x xs IH] //. case E: (a x)=> /=; rewrite E.
- rewrite addnC. rewrite addn1. rewrite eqSS. by rewrite -IH.
- rewrite addnC=> /=. rewrite addn0. rewrite -size_filter.
```

I got this state:

```
T : Type
a : pred T
x : T
xs : seq T
IH : all a xs = (count a xs == size xs)
E : a x = false
============================
false = (size [seq x <- xs | a x] == (size xs).+1)
```

How can I prove that `size [seq x <- xs | a x]` is always less then `(size xs).+1)`? So, their equality is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `count_size` lemma that says that `count a xs <= size xs`.  Then, it suffices to use `ltnn : forall n, (n < n) = false`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool ssrnat eqtype seq.

Lemma all_count T (a : pred T) s :
  all a s = (count a s == size s).
Proof.
  elim: s=> [| x xs IH] //. case E: (a x)=> /=; rewrite E.
- rewrite addnC. rewrite addn1. rewrite eqSS. by rewrite -IH.
- rewrite addnC=> /=. rewrite addn0.
  by case: (count a xs =P (size xs).+1) (count_size a xs) => // ->; rewrite ltnn.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid induction and case analysis, and only use rewrite, you can i.e. use `has_predC` and friends.

```
Proof.
    rewrite -(negbK (all a s)) -has_predC has_count -eqn0Ngt 
       -(count_predC a) -{1}(@addn0 (count a s)) eqn_add2l //.
Qed.
```